# ProtocolError : Protocol error (Page.createIsolatedWorld)

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, cheerio

I get the below error when trying to automate Zomato site with puppeteer. I've not been able to find much information about this error online. Can anyone help me in to know about this error?

My code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


console.log("before");

const link = "https://www.zomato.com/";

(async () => {
    try{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            slowMo: 250,
            args: ["--start-maximized"],
            defaultViewport: null,
          });
        
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(link,{waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
        await page.click(".sc-bke1zw-1.bcVYKA>a");

        await browser.close();
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Error:
[image: Error message]

Comment: I don't see any error when trying to reproduce your source code as it's run OK without any message error. Maybe your connection is broken, or chromium's puppeteer is not ready to run. Try to change `waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"` to `waitUntil: "load"` or add some more seconds to `timeout: 60000`, or set this to 0 as this will make the timeout disable.

Comment: Still getting the same error in terminal window